# Fragment replaced in activity does not show setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled arrow

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In my activity I have one `FrameLayout` that needs to be swapped out with another fragment on button press. When the second fragment is pushed, the actionbar does not show the back arrow.  However, pressing the back triangle does pop the second fragment and returns to the Main Fragment.

The initial Activity with the Main fragment

[image: The initial Activity with the Main fragment]

You can see that the second fragment is added, but the arrow is not present to take the user back. Even though in my NewCallFragment I have the line

`activity?.actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

My Activity

```
private const val TAG = "DashboardActivity"

class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit { add<MainFragment>(R.id.fragment_container, null, intent.extras) }
        }
    }


    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putCharSequence(TAG, title)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        if (supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()) {
            return true
        }
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


    class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_main) {
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNewCall).setOnClickListener {
                onShowNewCall()
            }
        }

        private fun onShowNewCall() {
            activity?.supportFragmentManager?.commit {
                replace<NewCallFragment>(R.id.fragment_container, null, null)
                addToBackStack(null)
            }
        }
    }


    class NewCallFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_new_call) {
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            activity?.actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            activity?.title = "My Second Fragment"
        }
    }

}
```

Activity Layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="@dimen/parent_padding"
    tools:context=".activitiesx.DashboardActivity">
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Main Fragment Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNewCall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10sp"
        android:text="@string/new_call"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**New Call Fragment Layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add new call"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use activity?supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I just tried and there is no `supportActionBar`

Comment: Interestingly, you are using replace and adding your fragment to the back stack. Have you tried using `add` instead of `replace`?

Comment: Using `add` overlays the second fragment over the old one. I can see the New Call button under my second fragment.

Comment: @user-44651 It is quite strange. getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); should work in any case.